# why does rand keep producing the same value every time in c++?

Tags: c++, random

I have the code

```
char a = 97 + rand() % 26;
char b = 97 + rand() % 26;
char c = 97 + rand() % 26;
char d = 97 + rand() % 26;
char e = 97 + rand() % 26;
char f = 97 + rand() % 26;
```

in my program, within the main file, and when I execute the file I get the sequence lvqdyo every time, when I assumed it would randomize every time. Any insight would be appreciated, whether or not it is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Random` is *not* really random. It is a rather a *pseudo* random which depends on the **seed**.

For *one* random seed, you have *one exact set* of *pseudo* random sequence. That's why you get the same result every time you run the program because *once compiled, the random seed doesn't change*.

In order to make your application having random like behavior every time you run it, consider of using time info as random seed:

```
#include <cstdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

....
srand (time(NULL)); //somewhere in the initialization
```

`time(NULL)` is the random seed which will change according to the system time you run your application. Then you could use your `rand()` with different random seed everytime:

```
//somewhere else after initialization
char a = 97 + rand() % 26;
char b = 97 + rand() % 26;
char c = 97 + rand() % 26;
char d = 97 + rand() % 26;
char e = 97 + rand() % 26;
char f = 97 + rand() % 26;
```

Answer (score 4):

Initialize a random seed first using `srand()`.
Current time can be used to do the same:

```
#include <cstdlib> // this is where srand() is defined
#include <ctime> // this is where time() is defined
srand (time(NULL));
char a = 97 + rand() % 26;
...
```

Refer [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/).

Such a random seed ensures that every subsequent call to `rand()` will produce a random number.

Answer (score 2):

To using a `rand()` you have to seed it first, see below example

```
/* rand example: guess the number */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

int main ()
{
  int iSecret, iGuess;

  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));

  /* generate secret number between 1 and 10: */
  iSecret = rand() % 10 + 1;

  do {
    printf ("Guess the number (1 to 10): ");
    scanf ("%d",&iGuess);
    if (iSecret<iGuess) puts ("The secret number is lower");
    else if (iSecret>iGuess) puts ("The secret number is higher");
  } while (iSecret!=iGuess);

  puts ("Congratulations!");
  return 0;
}
```

`srand(time(NULL))` made sure the seed is starting up so the `rand` can works properly

Reading source : 
[CPP - Rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)